# Android Proper Variable Declariation

Tags: java, android, variables, parse-platform, import

For some reason my username and password variables are red. When I define them as strings I get errors which say that they cannot be cast from edit text....Is there any way to actually fix this? It's irritating because I'm working from a tutorial verbatim and they appear to not have these issues. I have already tried doing various things such as turning password and username to Strings. It's just not working properly.

Here is what I've tried so far. I just want this simply login/signup code to work. (Code Updated)

```
package myapplication.example.com.cis490_project;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.parse.LogInCallback;
import com.parse.Parse;
import com.parse.ParseObject;
import com.parse.ParseUser;
import com.parse.SignUpCallback;

public class loginactivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button loginButton;
   Button signUpButton;
   EditText usernameField;
    EditText passwordField;

    String username;
    String password;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_loginactivity);

        loginButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btlogin);
        signUpButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btsignup);
        usernameField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.tusername);
        passwordField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.tpassword);


        // Enable Local Datastore.
        Parse.enableLocalDatastore(this);

        Parse.initialize(this, "SECRET_KEY", "SECRET_KEY");

        ParseObject testObject = new ParseObject("Testing");
        testObject.put("foo", "badr");
        testObject.saveInBackground();


        loginButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                username = usernameField.getText().toString();
                password = passwordField.getText().toString();
                ParseUser.logInInBackground(username, password, new LogInCallback() {
                    public void done(ParseUser user, com.parse.ParseException e) {
                        if (user != null) {
                            //start next activity
                            //start sinch service
                        } else {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                "There was an error logging in.",
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
                });
            }
        });
        signUpButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
               username = usernameField.getText().toString();
                  password = passwordField.getText().toString();
                ParseUser user = new ParseUser();
                user.setUsername(username);
                user.setPassword(password);
                user.signUpInBackground(new SignUpCallback() {
                    public void done(com.parse.ParseException e) {
                        if (e == null) {
                            //start next activity
                            //start sinch service
                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                    "There was an error signing up."
                                    , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }



    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_loginactivity, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}


XML:

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="myapplication.example.com.cis490_project.loginactivity">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Login"
        android:id="@+id/btlogin"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:text="Password"
        android:id="@+id/tpassword"
        android:layout_above="@+id/btlogin"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:text="Username"
        android:id="@+id/tName"
        android:layout_above="@+id/tpassword"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/tpassword"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/tusername"
        android:layout_marginBottom="40dp" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/iprofile"
        android:src="@drawable/com_facebook_profile_picture_blank_square"
        android:layout_above="@+id/tName"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/btlogin"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/btlogin"
        android:layout_marginBottom="56dp" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Signup"
        android:id="@+id/btsignup"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I did not get the error you described when changing `username = usernameField.getText().toString();` to `String username = usernameField.getText().toString();`.

Comment: You may want to revoke your Parse keys and create a new pair, they appear to be included in your code snippet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define all your widgets after `setContentView` inside `onCreate`. And define `username` and `password` as String variables. Because You did not define `username` and `password` anywhere in your code.

```
    public class loginactivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button loginButton;
    Button signUpButton;
    EditText usernameField;
    EditText passwordField;

    String username;
    String password;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_loginactivity);

        loginButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btlogin);
        signUpButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btsignup);
        usernameField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.tusername);
        passwordField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.tpassword);

        //rest of your code
        ..............
        }
```

Comment: This right here actually fixed a bit of my issue but I'm still getting some errors. here is my log cat.  http://pastebin.com/d8rGfJZD     For some reason there may still be a casting error.

Comment: logcat says that your edittext is null. Declare your edittexts after setContentView. see code of my answer

Comment: Looks like I'm still having the same problem. Just to be sure I have added to XML so you can see if anything there is set incorrectly. My top post should have my latest code and XML.

Comment: the id of usernamefield edittext is tName . not tusername

Comment: you are passing wrong id on username edittext. Use this : usernameField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.tName);

Comment: You are a life saver. Something so simple... I need to pay more attention to switching around ID names. Thanks!